# How to use the Scroll API with the ReactiveElasticsearchClient

Tags: elasticsearch, reactive-programming, project-reactor, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am new to reactive programming and I´m trying to switch to `ReactiveElasticsearchClient`.

Now the old code uses `RestHighLevelClient` and does a scroll search with a do-while loop like the following:

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = searchRequest(indexName)
        .source(searchSource()
                        .query(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
                        .fetchSource(true)
                        .sort("id", SortOrder.ASC)
                        .size(1000))
        .scroll(TimeValue.timeValueSeconds(60L));

SearchResponse searchResponse = restHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
SearchHits searchHits = searchResponse.getHits();
String scrollId = searchResponse.getScrollId();

do {
    /*
    * work with the search hits and
    * and do some logic here
    *
    * */

    SearchScrollRequest scrollRequest = new SearchScrollRequest(scrollId).scroll(TimeValue.timeValueSeconds(60));

    try {
        searchResponse = restHighLevelClient.scroll(scrollRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        searchHits = searchResponse.getHits();
        scrollId = searchResponse.getScrollId();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
    }

} while (searchHits.getHits().length > 0);

ClearScrollRequest clearScrollRequest = new ClearScrollRequest();
clearScrollRequest.addScrollId(scrollId);
restHighLevelClient.clearScroll(clearScrollRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

How can I do the same in a reactive pipeline with the `ReactiveElasticsearchClient`? Some of the classes that the `RestHighLevelClient` uses are not available for the reactive client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```java
Flux<SearchHit> ReactiveElasticsearchClient.scroll(SearchRequest request)
```

This method executes the given query using the scroll API under the hood. The `ReactiveElasticsearchClient` maintains the scroll id internally and fetches the next *batch* of data from Elasticsearch as the caller of the method consumes the returned `Flux<SearchHit>` until all data is fetched.

As for the classes used by `RestHighLevelClient` and `ReactiveElasticsearchClient`:

The `RestHighLevelClient` and the classes it uses come from the Elasticsearch libraries (rest-highlevel-client and Elasticsearch core). Spring Data Elasticsearch use the `RestHighLevelClient` to access Elasticsearch. When you are using the `RestHighLevelClient` directly you are not using Spring Data Elasticsearch but plain Elasticsearch code.

The `ReactiveElasticsearchClient` is provided by Spring Data Elasticsearch and not by Elasticsearch. It uses classes for input and output from the Elasticsearch libraries as well, but also classes from Spring Data Elasticsearch  or the Spring Framework. It's purpose is to enable the reactive access to Elasticsearch with Spring Data Elasticsearch. It's
functions are not a reactive copy of the `RestHighLevelClient` but are what is needed to implement the reactive access. So you will not find corresponding function in the `ReactiveElasticsearchClient` for every function of the `RestHighLevelClient`.